# What's this type of linear regression called in english

Tags: regression, linear

if regular linear regression is $$ E(y) = A +B x $$
then
$$ x_i'= {x_i - \bar x \above 1pt σ_x}, y_i'= {y_i - \bar y \above 1pt σ_y} $$
$$ E(y') = A' + B'x' $$
$$ A' = 0,  B' = r $$
what is this called : 
$$ E( y') = rx' $$

Comment: "Regular" linear regression is not $\widehat {y\,}=A+B\,\widehat x;$ rather it is $\widehat{y\,} = \widehat A + \widehat B x.$ The values of $A$ and $B$ are estimated; the values of $x$ are part of the observed data, so the diacritic -- the "hat" -- doesn't belong there.

Comment: Because it's mathematically the same thing, it's still called "linear regression."

Comment: "Simple linear regression without intercept term" in the best I can find. How do you call each of them in your native language?

Comment: This is regression with standardized coefficients. In simple linear regression (one predictor), the standardized coefficient on the predictor is equal to the correlation and the intercept is zero, just as you've written.

Comment: I'd call this 'regression with standardized variables'. The coefficients are only standardized as a consequence of the variables being standardized.

Comment: Alright thanks guys! that answers my question.